# Seeds on the outside

Tags: prepositions

> Why Does a Strawberry Have Seeds **On the** Outside?

Can we omit the preposition "on the" in the sentence above?
Is it necessarily?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary.

> Why does a strawberry have seeds outside?

^ This makes it sound like there is a strawberry sitting out on the front yard holding a bag of seeds. Or something equally as imaginative.